# angular timer returning NaN value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to make a timer in javascript, a very simple one. I wrote a bit of code that should have worked afaik, yet it doesn't, so I did something wrong. I cant figure out what I did wrong. after a second it changes the value of the textbox to NaN.

Here is the code:

```
<timer countdown='timeBonPlan' interval="1000" >{{days}} Jours, {{hours}}:{{minutes}}:{{seconds}}</timer>
```

and in my controller

```
$scope.timeBonPlan =  3765915.979;
```

i have use parseFoalt but it doesn't work
when i set the value in the html page its work

Comment: I had the same problem. Have you tried using double brackets? If not then, look at the code. I think you can pass the service to the controller and set countdown time there.

Comment: countdown is 2way bound countdownattr: '=countdown', you can set a property on the scope or integer value(special implementation is present for that). So `countdown='timeBonPlan'` should just work. i think issue was with floating value. please assign integer value

Comment: what is _timer_ directive? your own? if yes, so - provide code for it, if not provide link for doc

Comment: no, its an angular directive

Comment: can you provide link to documentation for this directive? are you sure that this standart angular directive? Where you find this directive?

Comment: http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/

Comment: provide what how you fill `timeBonPlan`

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, Was able to solve by using ng-if to check if contdown variable exist thus:

```
<timer ng-if="timeBonPlan" countdown='timeBonPlan' interval="1000" >{{days}} Jours, {{hours}}:{{minutes}}:{{seconds}}</timer>
```

I hope you find it useful

Answer (score 0):

You can try appending a `+` sign like

```
<timer countdown='+timeBonPlan' interval="1000" >{{days}} Jours, {{hours}}:{{minutes}}:{{seconds}}</timer>
```

Comment: doesn't work but when i make
<timer countdown='3348759847.445' interval="1000" >{{days}} Jours, {{hours}}:{{minutes}}:{{seconds}}</timer> it works

Comment: you can check value of `timeBonPlan` in template, maybe you are not getting the value `{{ timeBonPlan }}`